# Connect Google Apps Forms with Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Is there a possibility to connect Google Apps - Forms with Sheets?

What I want to do:
I created a survey now I have all the answers and I would like to present these in a proper way.

My solution right know:

I converted the answers from Forms into a Spreadsheet (this one I want to design a bit better). Therefore I am writing a script which copies the first row and column (by column) (where all of the questions are written) to another sheet (the sheet where I would like to display the answers in my way), where I list this single questions horizontally underneath each other.

Now I got all the questions from sheet1 into sheet2. 
Now my struggle: 
Every question of a form has answers, these answers I would like to copy besides the questions in sheet2 and count the frequency how often an answer was selected.

But I also want to display the answer to the question even it wasn't selected. So is there a possibility to connect Forms with sheets?

In attachment you will find a sketch of my idea of displaying the data.
[image: My idea]
Hopefully you understand my question.

Thanks guys.

Comment: After a couple of hours of searching I found out, that I can read the questions, which are items, by FormApp.getActiveForm().getItemById() . I will try to figure out, if this works

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to link the Google Form to the Google Sheet, this is a simple, automatic function of Google Forms that can be turned on. I have included a picture of where to find this option. It will ask you if you would like to create a new spreadsheet or link to an existing one. From there you can add more sheets and process the data as you see fit. If you need specified assistance in the processing of the data, please ask a new question.

[image: Link to Sheets]

Comment: Hi, sorry, but this is the way how I created sheet1.

I wanted to know if there is a possibility to get the "template" of the form into a sheet. 
Like the basic structure, e.g.: a question and the answers which belong to it.